# Show NLog output in debug window of asp.net core app

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, nlog

Is it possible to show what NLog (or builit-in debugger) is logging in the Visual Studio 2017 debug window?

I have NLog set to output to a file but for development it would be really handy to be able to see the debug messages in the debug window.  I can see articles written on how to do this with console but for asp.net project there isn't any console output, just the debug window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for Asp.Net Core, there are built-in logger providers like `Console` and `Debug` to write log to `Output Window`.

If you use `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)`, it will uses built-in providers `Console` and `Debug`, and you could check the output by **Output window-> Asp.NET Core Web Server** for a clean result.

For [Getting started with ASP.NET Core 2](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2) from `NLog`, it uses code below to clear all other log providers.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
    })
    .UseNLog()  // NLog: setup NLog for Dependency injection
    .Build();
```

If you also need log in the Debug window, you could modify code like below:

```
        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureLogging(logger => {
                logger.AddNLog();
                //logger.AddConsole(); //UnComment out this line if you did not use CreateDefaultBuilder
            })
            .Build();
```

Answer (score 5):

The easy solution is just to use the `OutputDebugString`-target (Supported on NetCore)

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/OutputDebugString-target

Example:

```
<targets>
  <target name="debugger" xsi:type="OutputDebugString" layout="${logger}::${message}"/>
</targets>

<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="debugger" />
</rules>
```

Alternative one could use `xsi:type="debugger"`:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Debugger-target